# Does Express and/or Restify sanitize incoming data out of the box?

Tags: reactjs, node.js, express, security, xss

Hopefully this is a simple question, since it seems like a basic security step, but I haven't been able to find much info on what functions or modules to implement to escape dangerous characters and sanitize user data.

Our app uses React on the front end and Node/Express on the backend. Most of the routes are managed by [Restify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-restify-mongoose), although we have some custom routes.

Given that malicious code can be injected post-React, we would need to ensure incoming data is sanitized prior to being saved in the database, or being returned to the frontend. Does Express or Restify do this by default or would it be necessary to use a module like [DOMPurify](https://github.com/cure53/DOMPurify) and clean the data in a pre-middleware in Restify?

Comment: I'm not aware of any sanitizing done by Express.  I think you have install middleware and/or some custom code to accomplish what you want depending upon what the payload is and what you need to protect.